# In $\Delta ABC$, let side $a = 8\sqrt2$, side $b = 8$ and $\measuredangle B = \frac{\pi }{6}$ radians. Find $\measuredangle A$

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried using the trig difference formulas but I ultimately arrive at $\tan(\measuredangle A - 30) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$ and don't know how to proceed from there. Is there an easier way to do this question?

Comment: why do you not know how to proceed from there?

Comment: @Chris2006 I'm looking at the 45-45-90 and 30-60-90 triangles and none of them give me that ratio. I could split it up into sin(30) * sin(45) but that still doesn't help me.

Comment: wait is the triangle a right triangle?

Comment: that information is not given. Can i assume it is?

Comment: no you cannot asumme it is.

Comment: "Can i assume it is? "  No.  Don't be a ASS (Angle, Side, Side).  But you can use law of sines.  $\frac {\sin B}{b} = \frac {\sin  A}{a}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines): $$\frac{\sin(A)}{a}=\frac{\sin(B)}{b}$$ where three of the four quantities above are known.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm How do you know there is a hypotenuse? We don't know that the triangle is right (nor do we need this assumption). We know the angle $B$, we know the side lengths $a$ and $b$. So just plug these values into the equation I provide (the sine law) and rearrange for $\sin(A)$. Then take inverse sine and you get $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cosine Rule formula $\cos B=\dfrac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}$ to get the value of $c$.

and then use the formula $\cos A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$ to find the $\measuredangle A$